# How to allow users of my site to login/register via Facebook and integrate Facebook login system with my own login system?

Tags: php, facebook

I am just lost and do not know where to begin, please show me documentation I can read to let users register/login to my site using Facebook.

Assuming that

- I have my own registration/login system

How can I

- Log in users with their Facebook profile
- Register users quickly with their Facebook profile if they are not registered

Any ideas or docs are appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Besides that, here you'll find all you need: http://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to register an facebook app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps. Then this code will be a good starting point for you:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
             client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&
             redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fecho%2F&
             fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
        scrolling="auto"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="400">
</iframe>
```

Full documentation of the registration plugin can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Comment: Answer is correct but it has been deprecated for the favor of the Graph API.
The new method of implementing FB login can be found here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0